# Laravel how to post input data to different page without database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

Hello iam new to laravel and iam trying to create form and post data from this form to different page without using database.

```
Route::get('main', function() {return view('main')});
Route::get('recieve', function() {return view('recieve')};
Route::post('posting', function() {return redirect(/recieve)->withName(Input::all());
```

In main.blade.php I got form and iam just using action="/posting" method="POST"

And inside recieve.blade.php iam trying to {{ &name->name}}

What should I do different?

Comment: `->withName(Input::get('name'))` and print `{{ $name }}` in your `receive` template.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd use controllers over directly use the route file but what you have is close.

Try

```
Route::post('/posting', function() 
{
   return redirect('/recieve')->with('name', Input::get('name'));
}
```

Then on the blade reference `{{ $name }}`

Comment: I tired dat and I just got 419 sorry your session has expired. After I press post it redirects me to posting and I got that error and function in route::post never executes and it do not redirect to recieve page

Comment: Missing single quotes from the redirect

Comment: Please make sure you have the csrf token on your form, you can do it by just adding @csrf inside your form html code in your blade.

Comment: I got @csrf still 419 error after submitting I got redirected to posting and got that error 419

Answer (score 0):

be surely that you've send any data make

```
var_dump(Input::all()) or dd(Input::get('name')
```

under your route if there's any data you'll see and you can do like you did

if you got your session as been expired you have to put a

```
@csrf
```

inside your form it's an hidden field to validate your form

Comment: What ever I try to do I always get 419 error sorry your session has expired and I can't find the problem

Comment: or you can use {{ csrf_field() }} inside the form

Comment: Tried still that error iam out of hope :D can't find the answer.

Comment: <form action="/posting" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="vardas">
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>

Comment: So why I got error 419 session has expired every time I try to submit? What can be the problem?

Comment: just make sure that you saved the modification or stop and re-run the server cause everything is ok

Comment: I tried to run my localhost in different browser not I dont get 419 error but for some reason it says variable that I use in blade is not declared even tho I sent It usint ->withName($variable)

Comment: when you use ->withName($variable) it's gonna be create a variable $name for you in your recieve you have it {{ dd($name) }} for debug or a var_dump($name)

Comment: If I try to use variable called name I got error thatt it was not declared even though I did declare it and dd(), vardump gives me same error that variable name was not declared, I tried route('route.name', ['name' => 'random.word'] it still said variable was not declared. For some reason I just can't pass any variable to my recieve view

Comment: inside your route $name = Input::all(); return redirect('/recieve')->withName($name); and that's all

Answer (score 0):

make sure your varaible name existe

```
Route::post('posting', function() {
   $name = Input::all();return redirect('/recieve',compact('name');
}
```